# getting rid of trailing output

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do i get rid of the extra character at the end of a line when i flush output?

Output:

```
{Fifth Level} Last Key Ran: 7 Output: -7  =
```

That '=' is what i want to get rid of.

code:

```
for number in str(fourth_level):
    x=int(number)
    x=x^(priv_key-pub_key)
    print "\r{Fifth Level} Last Key Ran:",str(number),"Output:",x,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    fifth_level.append(x)
```

Also is there any way to get multiple lines outputting data at the same time without going down one line or changing format? Using flush it gets rid of the second line output.

Comment: It also does vary in the trailing output, sometimes it is not just '='.

Comment: Your code doesn't print an =, so that's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @kindall Yes i found out what i was doing wrong. Thank you for the effort of checking it.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, check the `,x,` part of the print statement.  That 'x' is fishy.

For string manipulations, try writing everything into a temporary string first.  You can then edit that string.  This will give you more control over editing it.

Also, `rstrip` might do the trick if the characters being displayed are consistent.

Reference:
* http://docs.python.org/library/string.html
"string.rstrip(s[, chars]) Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed."